# Access Many-to-Many relationship data in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am new to django and trying to model a OOP concept.

I have model for actor and movies. Movie have many-to-many relationship with actor model.

**url.py**

```
from movies import views

url(r'^recent/$', views.recentlyadded, {'movieid': 1}),
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Actor(models.Model):
    actorid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1)

class Movie(models.Model):
    movieid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    actor = models.ManyToManyField(Actor)
```

**view.py**

```
from movies.models import *

def recentlyadded(request, movieid):
    m = get_object_or_404(Movie, pk = movieid)
    return render_to_response('search_results.html', {'movies': m})
```

**search_results.html**

```
{% if movies %}
    {{movies.title}}
        <ul>{{ movies.actor_set.all.count }}
            {% for actor in movies.actor_set.all %}
                <li>{{actor.name}}</li>
            {%endfor%}
        </ul>
{% endif %}
```

**Output**

```
The Dark Knight
```

I am not getting the actor list at all.

Should I use a intermediary model? If yes, what will happen if I have to associate directors to the movie model? How many intermediary model should be created?

Please help with the code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to access to `movies.actor` directly

```
{% if movies %}
    {{movies.title}}
    <ul>{{ movies.actor.all.count }}
        {% for actor in movies.actor.all %}
            <li>{{actor.name}}</li>
        {%endfor%}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me when to use '_set' or '_entry'? is it only in case of Foreign-key relationship?

Comment: You have declared the movies.actor m2m property, so you has direct access. In other way, you have indirect access from actor objects to movies actor.movies_set.all. Have a look to this: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/A5AKyk1VSfQ/85KFl-wNTM0J